# fragment data loads everytime fragment is called

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am creating an app which has bottom navigation and I am retrieving data using an api. I am calling api and assigning values to a `listview` in `fragment` in `oncreateview` method. But problem is this method is executed every time and api retrieves data every time fragment is called. What i want is that data should load only once when fragment is called first time and every other time listview should just display previously loaded data, I have no idea how to do this, please help if you know some other way of doing this.

this is how i am calling fragments

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_schedule:
                Fragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, scheduleFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_teams:
                Fragment teamFragment = new TeamFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, teamFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_champions:
                Fragment championsFragment = new ChampionsFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, championsFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_live:
                Fragment liveFragment = new LiveFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, liveFragment).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_records:
                Fragment recordsFragment = new RecordsFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main, recordsFragment).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

and this is how data is loaded in fragment

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView lvSchedule;

customAdapterSchedule adapterSchedule;
List<BeanSchedule> listSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
float x1, x2, y1, y2;

private static final String url = "https://wc19.000webhostapp.com/ad/class/api.php?method=schedule";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, null);

    lvSchedule = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvSchedule);





        adapterSchedule = new customAdapterSchedule(this.getContext(), listSchedule);
        lvSchedule.setAdapter(adapterSchedule);
        apiCall();

    return view;
}

public void apiCall(){
    JsonArrayRequest scheduleReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            BeanSchedule schedule = new BeanSchedule();

                           schedule.setTeam1name(obj.getString("team1name"));
                            schedule.setTeam2name(obj.getString("team2name"));
                            schedule.setTeam2img(obj.getString("team2img"));
                            schedule.setTeam1img(obj.getString("team1img"));
                            schedule.setDate(obj.getString("date"));
                            if(obj.getString("daynight").equals("0"))
                                schedule.setDaynight(" ");
                            else
                                schedule.setDaynight("Day/Night");

                            // Genre is json array


                            // adding movie to movies array
                            listSchedule.add(schedule);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"inside catch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                        }


                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapterSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(scheduleReq);

}
```

}

Comment: Provide your code . How fragments are arranged in Activity and transactions.

Comment: some code would be better

Comment: you need to save data in local storage (sqlite). and call it from sqlite onward.

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from setting a flag after you receive the data initially? I don't know how your code looks like, and your question isn't very elaborate either, but something like this should work:

```
boolean data_loaded_once = false;
```

and in your API callback function:

```
if(!data_loaded_once){
    data_loaded_once = true;
    // load data here
}
```

That being said, you probably shouldn't be having this problem at all.

EDIT: save the data somewhere else: `ListView` adapter (temporary) or SQLite.

Comment: the view of the fragement will be created every time even if i set the flag and call the fragment again the data won't be loaded and listview will be empty, which will show nothing in fragment

Comment: Like other people already mentioned, if you don't show us the code we cannot help you any further :(

Comment: @PriteshThaker you should set the flag in your ListView adapter (and consequently save the data there) not in the fragment.